# Why does using excludeSwitches in c#

Tags: c#, python, selenium

Python code works:

```
import time
from selenium import  webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])
```

But the C# code is not working:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("excludeSwitches", "disable-popup-blocking");
```

Comment: In C# is working for me using this sentence: chromeOptions.AddExcludedArgument("enable-automation");

Answer (score 7):

```
        List<string> ls = new List<string>();
        ls.Add("enable-automation");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddExcludedArguments(ls);
        using (IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\\Program\\chromedriver", options))
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to this out-of-nowhere code ? It will help OP if you explain what he was doing wrong, what your change to make it work, and why.

Answer (score 2):

I use "excludeSwitches" to get rid of the error showing on the output console.
[A device attached to the system is not functioning error using ChromeDriver Selenium on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system)

This is my code:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
List<string> ls = new List<string>();
ls.Add("enable-automation");
ls.Add("excludeSwitches");
ls.Add("enable-logging");
ls.Add("disable-popup-blocking");
options.AddExcludedArguments(ls); //set option element in list to options
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);  //open webdriver with your options
```