# Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning error using ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import pyautogui
import requests
import nltk   
import urllib.request
import random



driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.karsanj.net/login.php')
userm=driver.find_element_by_id('username')
userm.send_keys('gdbcfss')
time.sleep(2)
passwoord=driver.find_element_by_id('password')
passwoord.send_keys('fbxeedf')
time.sleep(2)
sal =driver.find_element_by_id("salTahsili")
sal.click()
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.press('down')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.press('enter')
time.sleep(2)
login=driver.find_element_by_name('login')
login.click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.get('https://www.karsanj.net/vschool_list.php')

def goonline():
    urlsite=driver.current_url()
        
def urlgetter(driver):
    time.sleep(7)
    try:
        onlineclass=driver.find_element_by_class_name('entrance-btn')
        onlineclass.click()
    except:
        print('no online classes in this time ')
    time.sleep(5)
    classon=driver.find_element_by_id('room_unique_url')
    classon.click()
    time.sleep(20)
    attend= driver.find_elements_by_class_name('tablet-beta-label')
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(15)
    try:
        pyautogui.click()
        close1=driver.find_elements_by_id('recording-locked-notifier_0')
        close1.click()
        close2=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('spectrum-Button spectrum-Button--secondary')
        close2.click()
    except:
        pass




urlgetter(driver)
```

When i run it give me this error at the end

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60683/devtools/browser/9b15c32e-ddc1-4ddd-9abe-bcf597ad4821
[4888:9376:1120/223739.924:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [22:37:39.924] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60683/devtools/browser/9b15c32e-ddc1-4ddd-9abe-bcf597ad4821
[4888:9376:1120/223739.924:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] 
[22:37:39.924] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) raised an error while in trying to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session.

---

### Analysis

This error surfaces on [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) systems due to an error in callback of an attached *USB* device which isn't functioning properly.

This error is defined within [usb_device_handle_win.cc](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/66.0.3359.158/device/usb/usb_device_handle_win.cc#578) as follows:

```
void UsbDeviceHandleWin::GotDescriptorFromNodeConnection(
    TransferCallback callback,
    scoped_refptr<base::RefCountedBytes> request_buffer,
    scoped_refptr<base::RefCountedBytes> original_buffer,
    Request* request_ptr,
    DWORD win32_result,
    size_t bytes_transferred) {
  std::unique_ptr<Request> request = UnlinkRequest(request_ptr);
  if (win32_result != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
    SetLastError(win32_result);
    USB_PLOG(ERROR) << "Failed to read descriptor from node connection";
    std::move(callback).Run(UsbTransferStatus::TRANSFER_ERROR, nullptr, 0);
    return;
  }
```

---

### Solution

This error isn't harmful and doesn't blocks the spawning of the new *Browsing Context*
i.e. the *Chrome Browser* session. So you can safely ignore the error.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection error with ChromeDriver v87 / Chrome v87 using Selenium on Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65080685/usb-usb-device-handle-win-cc1020-failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connectio)
- [Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning error using ChromeDriver Selenium on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system/64928509#64928509)