# easymc.io web scraping tying to extract a value

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to get as many easymc.io accounts keys as I can, I tried to get the value of a button but it doesn't and when I'm trying to find the element_by_xpath it says that the xpath does not exist

```
#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\Downloads\chromedriver_win\chromedriver.exe'
options = Options()
options.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
driver.get('https://easymc.io/get?new')
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/input')
```

Comment: What input tag are you referencing to. Post the html element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scrape the value of the *accounts keys* e.g. `8yBAnUFoNlj3JJHzFE7t` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://easymc.io/get?new')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control[aria-label='Alt Token']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://easymc.io/get?new')
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='form-control' and @aria-label='Alt Token']"))).get_attribute("value"))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  8yBAnUFoNlj3JJHzFE7t
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)

Comment: @leom4lifesw Those are ChromeDriver/Chrome callback errors specifically observed on windows platform which aren't harmful and shouldn't affect your tests. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64940553/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system/64947966#64947966) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system/64928509#64928509) discussion.