# Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F) When trying to execute Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm executing a very simple selenium call:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver_path = r"C:\Windows\chromedriver.exe"
url = "http://www.google.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get(url)
```

Although the browser opens and navigates to the location, I'm getting a really strange error:

```
[9232:7300:1130/164722.426:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [16:47:22.426] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

I've not encountered this before, it's literally started happening today. I've had a good browse trying to find a solution but the closest thing I've found is this answer: [Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning error using ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64940553/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system/64947966#64947966)

But it just states that it can be ignored, well that's not the best option..

The error holds control of the console until you hit enter, so if I have anything else being called after the python script it's just going to hang.

Does anyone at all have any idea why this has started happening all of a sudden?