# I can't send WhatsApp message using Selenium :/ with these error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, message, whatsapp

## Error while running my Selenium automation

I cannot completely run my project as it is shown error soon after rendering the web.whatsapp.com

### This is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
import time 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe') 

driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/") 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600) 

target = '"D@D"'

string = "Message sent using Python!!!"

x_arg = '//span[contains(@title,' + target + ')]'
group_title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(( 
    By.XPATH, x_arg))) 
group_title.click() 
inp_xpath = '//div[@class="input"][@dir="auto"][@data-tab="1"]'
input_box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(( 
    By.XPATH, inp_xpath))) 
for i in range(100): 
    input_box.send_keys(string + Keys.ENTER) 
    time.sleep(1)
```

### Following are the errors :/

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:7568/devtools/browser/4166a9d5-5e52-4d35-98da-769f457998e7
[17452:12364:1123/234409.011:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [23:44:09.012] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node 
connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[17452:12364:1123/234409.041:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [23:44:09.041] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node 
connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

### Cannot find any other solutions on web

### Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are doing the below:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')`

Use the below if you dont want to specify the location because you might not now where it is at:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome()`

Is your chrome in your D, F, etc... drive?

Example:

`driver = webdriver.Chrome("F:\\chromedriver.exe")`

Comment: That should give a different error. Something about `chromedriver` not being in PATH

Comment: This error can be ignored but in most cases, the webdriver isn't pathing correctly. I found a similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system