# Python Selenium Webdriver/Chromedriver (Device attached is not functioning...)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I used **Selenium** to display the website.
This is my code right here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'SELE/chromedriver.exe')

browser.get("https://lolprofile.net/")
```

The code does runs, but the website only appeared for a second and then this set of problem code occurs:

```
[15696:7680:1231/111918.721:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [11:19:18.721] USB: 
usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the 
system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

and now I can't continue the next step of my coding.

Comment: Hello Jamuxi, I think your issue is similiar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error , but a warnign and it doesn't affect the run.

Browser closing is because python garbage collector is closing the chromedriver once the code execution completes

you can just add `time.sleep()` , or ask some user `input("Enter any key to exit:")` to stop code from exiting

Answer (score 0):

yes, I added the following code and it waits 3 seconds before closing...

```
    import time 
    << your chrome get code goes here >> 
    time.sleep(3)
```

I've seen some people get around this error message, but it's not trivial.

Try This...

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get('https://something.com/login')
    driver.maximize_window()
```