# Error using selenium on windows usb_device_handle_win.cc

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hi everybody i'm new here and i have this error when i run this [repository](https://github.com/NoNameoN-A/TikTok-Follow-Heart-Views-Bot)

> [13288:10444:0219/125337.161:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)]
> [12:53:37.161] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read
> descriptor from node connection: Un dispositivo collegato al sistema
> non Þ in funzione. (0x1F)

I tried to search on google but i found that i need to remove usb devices from my pc and i did but i didn't solve. Can you help me?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system/65497385#65497385) solutions

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65497385/14759065) answer your question?

Comment: Nope, i didn't solved using this solution :-/