# Using Selenium with Excel/VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium from a very simple VBA-program:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim d As New WebDriver
    Const URL = "https://www.google.com/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome", URL
        .get URL
        .findElementById("lst-ib").SendKeys "Selenium basic GitHub"
        .FindElementsByTag("form")(1).FindElementByCss("input[value='Google Search']").Click
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

It is returning:
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.8.241075) on port 53354

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12485/devtools/browser/122b6be9-ae8f-44b0-b016-65729d831e8b
[19900:8256:0809/142126.875:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [14:21:26.875] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Een apparaat dat op het systeem is aangesloten, werkt niet. (0x1F)

Can anybody help? I've found some discussions on this issue on Internet, but until yet not a clear answer.

Comment: Does it stop the program from running? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system  And does your chrome browser version correspond to the chromedriver?

Comment: It opens Google Chrome with data; as URL and it is giving me an error message You are using an unsupported command line marker: --ignore-certifcate-errors. Stability and security will suffer. Coding stops at findElementbyID with the message: an exception with a null response was thrown sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL. The status of the exception was receiveFailure

Comment: And does your chromedriver version match browser version?

Comment: How can I check?

Comment: Look in your chrome browser help > about for version and check against https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads  for appropriate driver. Then check the driver which is being used.

Comment: driver being used shows Starting ChromeDriver (v2.8.241075) on port 53897 This seems to be very old? Even not listed at the download page?? How can I upgrade?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57216623/using-google-chrome-in-selenium-vba-installation-steps