# Getting an error while working on a selenium project

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to selenium and I am learning it by following a Youtube video tutorial. I don't know why the hell I am getting this weird error while running my automation script

**Error---**
[2520:5920:0905/012434.497:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [01:24:34.498] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[2520:5920:0905/012434.500:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [01:24:34.501] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)

Comment: Upload your code so we could see what could go wrong and where

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning error using ChromeDriver Selenium on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out these answers from previously asked posts and other websites:

- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system)
- [stackoverflow search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BSelenium%5D+A+device+attached+to+the+system+is+not+functioning)
- [Newbedev](https://newbedev.com/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-functioning-error-using-chromedriver-selenium-on-windows-os)
- [Flutterq](https://flutterq.com/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-functioning-error-using-chromedriver-selenium-on-windows-os/)

Most suggest to either ignore it or disable it with methods like the one mentioned by [Ofek Glick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69058608/16806945) in this post.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system) your error is probably coming from a chromedriver issue, and you can try to do the following to fix it:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```