# usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection

Tags: python, selenium, visual-studio-code

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.hotstar.com/in")
driver.find_element_by_id("searchField").send_keys("Movies")
```

Error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60918/devtools/browser/7a040891-218c-496d-bc9e-e8531e60e3f2
PS C:\Users\jaina\Desktop\Jainam\Codeing\New folder> [8476:4996:0912/183711.395:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:37:11.396] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning error using ChromeDriver Selenium on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system)