# Python Selenium : Failed to read descriptor from node

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im working on **scraping** News From https://finance.detik.com/indeks. I work on Windows OS with VS code as code editor. Somehow my program can open web browser but can't read WebElement and give error like this :

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54867/devtools/browser/ed90b4ff-9d7d-40b5-974b-edfc955e2410
> **[6384:8844:0925/194226.820:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:42:26.820] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)** 
> **[6384:8844:0925/194226.821:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [19:42:26.821] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:713 GetBluetoothAdapterStaticsActivationFactory failed: Class not registered (0x80040154)**

this is my code :

```
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://finance.detik.com/indeks")
sleep(3)
# The code below usually results in an error WebElement not found
# ---------------------------------------------------------
article = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("just_test")
#---------------------------------------------------------- 
for i in article:
    print(i)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

I've been looking for the solution in [Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning error using ChromeDriver Selenium on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system) but nothing work on me. I hope you guys know the answer.. Thanksss :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add options in my case I used this to ignore different *Bluetooth* and *USB* messages

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--disable-webgl")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
path = r'chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path,options=options)
```

Comment: sorry low response. this help me to ignore the error. but webdriver still cant read the element. btw this issues fixed but i dont know why

Comment: This worked for me, and I tried `enable-logging` on its own and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting the same error as you've got. But I ran the below code in my local.

1. Use `find_elements` to list all the article.
2. Use JS to scroll to each element.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://finance.detik.com/indeks")
time.sleep(3)
size_of_scrapper = len(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//article"))

j = 1
for i in range(size_of_scrapper):
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//article)[{j}]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
    inner_value = element.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//descendant::h3/a").get_attribute('innerText')
    print(inner_value)
    j = j + 1
```

**Output :**

> Generasi Milenial Didorong Terjun ke Dunia Pertanian, Bagaimana
> Caranya? Catat! Bantuan Subsidi Gaji Rp 1 Juta Tak Kena Potongan Putri
> Nia Daniaty Tersandung Dugaan Penipuan CPNS, BKN Ingatkan Hal Ini Biar
> Pariwisata Moncer Lagi, Maskapai-Travel Online Kasih Diskon Nih!
> Petani Singkong di Lampung Ini Raup Cuan Rp 150 Juta Lho Per Tahun Apa
> itu Dana Alokasi Khusus yang Bikin Azis Syamsuddin Terjerat KPK?
> Petani Lampung Raup Omzet Rp 150 Juta per Tahun dari Tanam Singkong
> Siap-siap! PeduliLindungi Mau Diuji Coba di Pasar Ada yang Baru Naik,
> Ini Daftar Harga Terbaru BBM Pertamina Kerek Harga, Mendag Mau Serap
> Telur Peternak buat Bansos Perajin Layangan Naga Panen Cuan Kala
> Pandemi Melanda 4 Fakta Tol Semarang-Demak Dibangun Pakai Bambu 
> Kemnaker Bahas Hubungan Industrial Pascapenetapan UU Cipta Kerja Jadi
> Tersangka Kasus Suap, Azis Syamsuddin Punya Gaji Segini Besar Sosok
> Hui Ka Yan, Buruh Pabrik yang Jadi Pemilik Evergrande Deretan Kantor
> BUMN yang Mau Dibubarkan, Dari Ruko hingga Gedung Tinggi KAI Gandeng
> BNPT Cegah Terorisme dan Radikalisme, Begini Caranya Hutama Karya Buka
> Banyak lowongan, Yang Mau Lamar Perhatikan Hal Ini! Jejak Pengutang
> BLBI Suyanto Gondokusumo, Pernah Punya Saham CFC Dear Penumpang KRL!
> Ini Tempat Naik-Turun Baru di Stasiun Manggarai

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: yap , thats not because my code, i dont why but on another device/pc/laptop thats work as usual. i want to fix that error in my laptop