# Why can't the fieldset won't to fill auto when I tried to use automation code?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("http://localhost:4200")


elem = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("test")
driver.close()
```

I'm learning to make automation code. When I tried to fill the username with that code, the program won't fill the username column. These is the error messages

> $ [15764:12120:1004/103725.917:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)]
> [10:37:25.917] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read
> descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is
> not functioning. (0x1F)
> [15764:12120:1004/103725.921:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)]
> [10:37:25.921] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read
> descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is
> not functioning. (0x1F)
> [15764:10488:1004/103725.929:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(228)]
> crbug.com/1216328:  Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please
> report if there is no report that this ends.
> [15764:10488:1004/103725.932:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(231)]
> crbug.com/1216328:  Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
> [15764:10488:1004/103725.949:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(234)]
> crbug.com/1216328:  Checking default browser status started. Please
> report if there is no report that this ends.
> [15764:10488:1004/103726.019:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(238)]
> crbug.com/1216328:  Checking default browser status ended.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning error using ChromeDriver Selenium on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system)

Comment: No, that doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Selenium with Python then add these extra options into your Selenium code to avoid these Console errors-

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```