# ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [11:32:41.457] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1045

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

when I run the code below on VSCode I get an error like this

ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [11:32:41.457] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1045 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. **(0x1F)**

**my code is**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com")

time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning error using ChromeDriver Selenium on Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system)