# Unable to click the "Sign In" button on MyWorkdayJobs login

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rpa

Hi I'm trying to click a button using python in selenium for the page https://walmart.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/login and I tried with both XPATH and ID used click, `send_keys(Keys.enter)`, submit but still is not clicking. Can anyone help me please?

[image]

```
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe,chrome_options=options")
# Load webpage
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window() # For maximizing window
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds
# Find first name field and fill it out
email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='input-4']").send_keys("1234@gmail.com");
passw = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='input-5']").send_keys("1233@1102");
sub = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@id='input-5']").send_keys(Keys.TAB + Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Please give more clarifications when you ask something here : what errors do you encounter ? Could you show some code ? Have you tried to print the visible elems to the console, to check if selenium detects the element in the first place ?

Comment: I'm getting an error saying " USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)".

Comment: Do any of [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64927909/failed-to-read-descriptor-from-node-connection-a-device-attached-to-the-system) help you ?

Comment: Nope I tried all

Comment: Could you edit your question to add an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: The code should work fine, your link is incorrect tho (404 page)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the correct URL to log in on the above-mentioned portal is:
https://walmart.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/WalmartExternal/login

Now, you're right, it doesn't let us log in simply by clicking on the `Sign In` button when we try to do an automation login using `Selenium` or I would say any other automation tool.

I have noticed that it does perform the click when we try to apply `click()` on the `Sign In` button but nothing happens afterward.

My friend, after many hit and trail using different things, I'm able to bring you the solution.

Here is the solution:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")


driver = Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://walmart.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/WalmartExternal/login"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[data-automation-id="email"]')))
email = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[data-automation-id="email"]')
email.send_keys('your_username')

password = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[data-automation-id="password"]')
password.send_keys('your_password')

submit = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[aria-label="Sign In"]')

hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(submit)
hover.click().perform()

time.sleep(10)
```

Few things to note:

1. The correct URL to log in is https://walmart.wd5.myworkdayjobs.com/en-US/WalmartExternal/login
2. we need to wait for the `Sign In` box to appear on the page.
3. we must pass the `user-agent` to the Chrome options.
4. Use `ActionChains` to successfully perform the click to get to the logged-in profile. A simple `click()` will not work here.

I hope it solves your problem. Cheers!